# How KVM (Kilo Virtual Machine) different from JVM(Java Virtual Machine)?

Tags: java, java-me, jvm, kvm

I have basic idea on Kilo Virtual Machine on Mobiles  , I have clear idea of how JVM  works  class loaders , Executable Engine,Method Area etc .

- Technically how KVM differs from JVM ?
- Does KVM increases the execution time as compared to JVM ?
- Any Performance Oriented difference ?
- Memory management

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_virtual_machine) doesn't perform class unloading and doesn't support custom class loaders.

The official Sun Ltd KVM only supports CLDC 1.0 and therefore does contain API-level bugs that were only fixed in CLDC 1.1.

The focus of the requirements when developing the KVM was on memory footprint so you can expect performance trade-offs to increase cpu usage (i.e. less buffering...).

Thread scheduling is slightly different but it's nothing that would impact Thread-safe application code.